# router administrator change Wi-Fi channel programmatically with android

Tags: android, wifi, router, frequency, channel

i would like if my question is possible or not.
Well every channel has a specefic frequency 1 à 13(2,4GHz), 36 to 64(5GHz) and  100 to 165(5GHz). 
for example :
channel number 1 : 2412GHz ;channel number  2 : 2417GHz.
Well when we enter to the router interface from the localhost address ,we can easely choose a channel.
What i would like to do is to change the channel programmatically (from my android app ) .
I have an idea ,but i don't know if it's feaseble or not ,is to simulate the router web interface and do the same work that it doeas with android.
if someone has an idea please help me 
PS: 'm the router adminsrator
Thank you

Comment: If you can find a remote management interface for the router, you can write a program to use that.  But figuring out the remote management interface you'd be targeting is an administration question and so not on topic here.  Essentially, you can't write a program until you can describe "in words" exactly what the program needs to do.

Comment: I edited my question to be more procise. Do you know an example ,or tutorial of a programm to manage the router interface ,i just need the idea (not the code , i'll right it by my self)

Comment: sory for my question ,i just don't know from where to begin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that is possible you connect to your router by SSH, and then, you change the configuration, and restart wireless, but, then, you will lost connection when channel changes.

However, I dont know if your router allow this operation with SSH

I have another idea:
With wireshark, see the HTTP packet sent between your PC and your router, when you does Login, and when you save configuration. If you understand them, maybe you make a new packet in your phone.

(sorry my English)

Comment: thank you ,well i don't care if the connction is lost (i'm trying to test the speed connection of all chanels ).the both idea are intresting, do have a document or site..containing concrit information ?

Comment: Hi, sorry i dont have documents for you.
I think that if your router have a DD-WRT firmware, is more fast to found documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to configure the router with SSH.

Comment: do you know  tutorial for that ?